# Spring Data JPA: Use Page with IN-Clause on Oracle DB

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-data-jpa

I want to build with my spring boot app + thymeleaf a pagination. To archive this my repository implements the `JpaRepository`. Now I don't want to use the `Page<T> findAll()` function but I want to use my own function. In this Query I've got a IN clause like this:

```
SELECT car FROM CarEntity car WHERE car.producer IN (:producers)
```

In my code it can be possible that the list behind `:producers` can have more than 1000 entries and our oracle database throws an exception because of the limitation.
At the moment I don't use 'Page' as return type, instead I get a `List<T>` of the selected items and then split it dependent on my actual page and return the sublist. The code looks like this:

```
public List<Car> getCarsByCarProducers(List<CarProducer> pCarProducers) {
    return pCarProducers.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> counter.getAndIncrement() / pChunkSize))
        .values()
        .stream()
        .map(partitionedList -> myCarRepository.getCarsByProducers(partitionedList))
        .flatMap(List::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: can you show your split code

Comment: I added an example in my original post